# Select distinct count usage divided by month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, distinct

I do have a table `license_Usage` which works like a log of the usage of licenses in a day

```
ID   User        license    date
1    1            A        22/1/2015
2    1            A        23/1/2015
3    1            B        23/1/2015
4    1            A        24/1/2015
5    2            A        22/2/2015
6    2            A        23/2/2015
7    1            B        23/2/2015
```

Where I want it to return the count of licenses of the day of the month with most usage of licenses the result should look like:

```
   User          Jan           Feb   
    1             2             1        ...
    2             0             2
```

I know I can get the total of licenses in a month using this query:

```
SELECT vlu.[Userkey],
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 1 THEN 1 END) as JAN,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 2 THEN 1 END) as FEB,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 3 THEN 1 END) as MAR,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 4 THEN 1 END) as APR,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 5 THEN 1 END) as MAY,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 6 THEN 1 END) as JUN,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 7 THEN 1 END) as JUL,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 8 THEN 1 END) as AUG,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 9 THEN 1 END) as SEP,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 10 THEN 1 END) as OCT,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 11 THEN 1 END) as NOV,
COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH = 12 THEN 1 END) as DEC
FROM license_usage vlu 
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT MONTH(vlu.EndDate)) AS CA(Month)
WHERE vlu.[EndDate] >='2015-01-01'
      AND vlu.[EndDate] < '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY vlu.[Userkey]
```

How can I get it to return my results?

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be0b4/1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the maximum by day usage per month for each user.  The basic data you want is:

```
select UserKey, month(license_usage) as mm, day(license_usage) as dd,
       count(distinct license) as cnt
from license_usage vlu
where vlu.EndDate] >= '2015-01-01' and vlu.EndDate < '2016-01-01'
group by UserKey, month(license_usage), day(license_usage);
```

Then you can pivot this in several ways, such as using conditional aggregation:

```
select UserKey,
       max(case when mm = 1 then cnt else 0 end) as Jan,
       . . .
from (select UserKey, month(license_usage) as mm, day(license_usage) as dd,
             count(distinct license) as cnt
      from license_usage vlu
      where vlu.EndDate] >= '2015-01-01' AND vlu.EndDate < '2016-01-01'
      group by UserKey, month(license_usage), day(license_usage)
     ) umd
group by UserKey;
```

`CROSS APPLY` is an interesting approach, but I can't think of a simpler way to get this information.

Comment: hello Gordon, thanks for the reply, yes you got it right, but your answer produces the same as my cross apply query =(. And I suppose that when you used month(license_usage) by license_usage you meant the endate column

Comment: This query returns the distinct count by user, what I need its to transform it by month
select MONTH(vlu.EndDate) as monthId,vlu.Userkey, COUNT(distinct vlu.idPackage) as QuantityofLicensesUsed  
 from license_usage as vlu
 Group by vlu.Userkey,vlu.EndDate

Comment: @Eduardox23 . . . Oh, I guess you want `count(distinct)` rather than `count(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it by using distinct on the Count (*)

```
select umd.pbrUserkey,
       max(case when mm = 1 then cnt else 0 end) as Jan,
       max(case when mm = 2 then cnt else 0 end) as Feb,
       max(case when mm = 3 then cnt else 0 end) as Mar,
       max(case when mm = 4 then cnt else 0 end) as Apr,
       max(case when mm = 5 then cnt else 0 end) as May
from (select vluk.pbrUserkey, month(vluk.EndDate) as mm, day(vluk.EndDate) as dd,
             count(distinct vluk.idPackage) as cnt
      from [license_usage] as vluk
      where vluk.[EndDate] >= '2015-01-01' AND vluk.[EndDate] < '2016-01-01'
      group by vluk.Userkey, month(vluk.EndDate), day(vluk.EndDate)
     ) umd
group by umd.Userkey;
```